# Variable with $ in value shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have variable - with value "RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD" but when i do 
export TASK_UID=$1
where $1 is argument to shell script i.e RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD
It ignores anything after $ it only gives me "RzQh"

Please , suggest so that it will consider value as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TASK_UID=$1` is most likely not the problem. The problem is how the script is called.

Without proper quoting (or escaping the `$`) when calling the script, the argument will be already expanded, meaning, the `$TaH6Vq5bD" is treated as a variable, which if not defined, results in nothing. And your script will never know about it.

The script tst.ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
TASK_UID=$1
echo "$TASK_UID"
```

will act as follows

```
prompt $ tst.ksh RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD
RzQh
prompt $ tst.ksh "RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD"
RzQh
prompt $ tst.ksh 'RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD'
RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD
prompt $ tst.ksh RzQh\$TaH6Vq5bD
RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD
prompt $ argument='RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD'
prompt $ tst.ksh $argument
RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with escape sequence

```
Replace RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD with RzQh\$TaH6Vq5bD
```

It will works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes:

```
a='RzQh$TaH6Vq5bD'
```

or just escape the `$` with a `\` like so:

```
a="RzQh\$TaH6Vq5bD"
```

Both will retain the original value without trying to process it as a variable.